# spark warning "block locks were not released by tid" leads to poor performance

Tags: performance, apache-spark, locking, warnings, take

I'm trying to demonstrate a simple clustering algorithm. Let's say I find k items on my rdd that represent a cluster for me. The problem is when I try to take() them to the driver, I get a warning saying " block locks were not released by tid ". This also leads to poor performance... 20 iterations of the code below take 11 seconds on 4-cores with a 2MB dataset. That is way worse than my serial version. Good thing is that I still get the correct results. Take a look please:

First, I take one item. Any item will do

```
List<Tuple2<Long, Instance>> selectedTuple = dataset.take(1);
        Instance selected = selectedTuple.get(0)._2;
```

Then I create an object that will find candidate items for my cluster based on the selected item I just found. For the record, it implements `PairFlatMapFunction`

```
        NCPComparator comp = new NCPComparator(meta, selected);
```

The next step finds some candidates

```
        JavaPairRDD<Long, Double> candidates = this.dataset.mapPartitionsToPair(comp);
```

But now, I need the k one's with the lowest Double value, so I implemented a `TupleComparator`. Then I invoke `takeOrdered`

```
        List<Tuple2<Long, Double>> groupList = candidates.takeOrdered(k, new TupleComparator());
```

At this point, that warning appears. Same goes for invoking `top()`. And as an iterative algorithm, it appears in every iteration. I am not showing you the rest of the code. You guessed it.. it's more than trivial :-)

Also, I did proper persist my rdds. Jobs seem to be working like a charm. I found out that lots of people have this problem but there is no answer.

Comment: Please report back if you figure anything out! I'm getting the same errors using the spark-redshift package, when writing data to redshift.  :)

Comment: No such luck friend. I learnt to live with it.